# Protocol implementation on a class with @MainActor - how to avoid warnings?

Tags: swift, swiftui

If we have a simple protocol and class implementation like the following;

```
protocol Solution: ObservableObject {
   var result: String { get set }
   func calc() async
}

@MainActor
class Solve: Solution {
   @Published
   var result: String = ""

   func calc() async { // operate on actors to find the result
      result = "the answer" 
   }
}
```

Xcode will show a yellow warning : "Main actor-isolated property 'result' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement" against the class definition of result.

Removing @MainActor will remove the warning, but then we need to manually `Dispatch` updates to result to ensure they are done on the main thread.
Is there a cleaner way to do this? Perhaps by amending the protocol?

Comment: This came about when monkeying around with actors and how to operate on them in a SwiftUI view. It seemed I needed to create an async context in order to use await.. on the actor methods, which then required that the SwiftUI view calls calc in a Task enclosure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `MainActor` to the `protocol`

```
@MainActor
protocol Solution: ObservableObject {
   var result: String { get set }
   func calc() async
}
```

I would give `actor` a look too, it all depends on the purpose of this `class`.

If its purpose is to update UI then wrapping the class is natural.

Comment: not sure, but looks like if you wrap just the class and then use the protocol somewhere it won't work. Looks like attributes do not automatically applied to protocols if class is marked with this attribute

Comment: @IvanTkachenko no protocols don’t actually conform to their attributes.

Answer (score 3):

The least intrusive solution is

```swift
@MainActor var result: String { get set }
```